# How to know if convex-hull of a set contains zero?

Tags: co.combinatorics, convex-polytopes, convex-geometry

Let $(\lambda_1 , \cdots , \lambda_d) \vdash k$ be a partition of $k$ of length $d$. Is there any way to decide if $0 \in \text{Conv}\{(\underbrace{\alpha_1, \cdots, \alpha_1}_{\lambda_1}, \cdots , \underbrace{\alpha_d , \cdots, \alpha_d}_{\lambda_d}) \in \mathbb{Z}^k: \, (\alpha_1, \cdots , \alpha_d) \in \mathbb{Z}^d,\, \sum_{i=1}^d \alpha_i = 0\}$, where not all $\alpha_i$s are zero?

Comment: I don't understand what the set is of which you're taking the convex hull. The way it's written now it seems like the set is $\{\lambda_i\alpha_i:i=1,\ldots,d\}$ which is a set of integers, not a set of points in $\mathbb{Z}^d$.

Comment: Sorry for that! I rewrote it and hopefully it is clear now.

Comment: Convex combination preserves the property that the first $\lambda_1$ coordinates are the same, etc. That is, if all the $\lambda_i$ are positive, the question is equivalent to simply if $0\in\mathrm{Conv}\{(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_d)\in\mathbb Z^d:\sum_{i=1}^d\alpha_i=0\}$. Either way, the answer is trivially yes, as $0$ (by which I assume you mean $(0,\dots,0)$) is already in the given set. Or am I missing something?

Comment: OK, the new formulation parses, but also seems like it must be wrong. $0\in\mathbb{Z}^k$ is a point of the set, so obviously it is in its convex hull.

Comment: I am sorry guys! Added one more edit. In fact, we know that $\alpha_1 \geq \alpha_2 \geq \cdots \geq \alpha_d$.

Comment: Well, with this last added detail, you should be able to see that $\alpha_d<0$ always, so the convex hull cannot contain 0.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Could you please give me a reference for the property you mentioned? Can we extend that property when we have $k$ different non-zero vectors $\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}^d$ (similar to the one I asked [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/278573/does-the-convex-hull-of-a-set-contain-zero-ii))?

Comment: The property I mentioned is a trivial consequence of the fact that covnex combination preserves linear equations (and inequalitites): the constraint here is just $x_1=x_2=\dots=x_{\lambda_1}$, which is $\lambda_1-1$ linear equations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like Emil noted in the comments, the question is equivalent to whether $0\in\mathrm{Conv}(\{\alpha\in\mathbb{Z}^d: \sum_{i=1}^{d}\alpha_i=0\}\setminus\{0\})$. To see that it is, note that it is the average of $(d-1,-1,-1,\ldots,-1)$ and its permutations.

Answer (score 1):

Given $n$ points $x_i \in \mathbb R^d$, $0$ is in their convex hull iff 
there is no $y \in \mathbb R^d$ such that $y \cdot x_i \ge 1$ for all $i$.
You can use linear programming software to check this.