# Does the convex-hull of a set contain zero (II)?

Tags: co.combinatorics, convex-geometry, convex-analysis

Let $(\lambda_1, \cdots , \lambda_d) \vdash k$ be a partition of $k$ of length $d$. Suppose we have $k$ non-zero vectors $\alpha^{(j)} = (\alpha^{(j)}_1, \cdots , \alpha^{(j)}_d) \in \mathbb{Z}^d$, such that $\sum_{i=1}^d \alpha_i^{(j)} = 0$ and $\alpha_1^{(j)} \geq \cdots \geq \alpha_d^{(j)}$, for $1 \leq j \leq k$. Does the origin belongs to the convex-hull of the following set?
\begin{equation}
\{ ( \underbrace{\alpha_1^{(j_1)}, \cdots, \alpha_1^{(j_1)}}_{\lambda_1}, \cdots , \underbrace{\alpha_d^{(j_d)}, \cdots , \alpha_d^{(j_d)}}_{\lambda_d} ) \in \mathbb{Z}^k: \, j_i \in \mathcal{J}_i \subset [k], \, |\mathcal{J}_i| = \lambda_i, \, 1 \leq i \leq d \}.
\end{equation}
In a simpler version that I asked [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/278529/how-to-know-if-convex-hull-of-a-set-contains-zero), the answer is no.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, the answer should still be no for the same reason ($\alpha_d^{(j)}<0$ for all $j$), unless the zero vector is one of your alpha vectors.

Comment: You mean that the sets $\mathcal{J}_i$ are fixed? That they form a partition of $[k]$, and only $j_i\in \mathcal{J}_i$ vary?

Comment: @FedorPetrov Yes, that is what I meant.